# @media screen CSS rule not working on smartphones

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to hide a specific section of my home page only at smartphone devices.

I'm using the code below but it still showing on my phone. Any advice?

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {

        #statistics .row {
            visibility: hidden;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        #statistics .row .columns {
            visibility: hidden;
            width: auto;
            margin-top: 3em;
            background: #fff;
            color: #444;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 85%; 
        }

        #statistics .timer.count-title.count-number {
            visibility: hidden;
            color: #c22362;
            font-size: 35px;
            margin-bottom: 8%
        }

        #statistics .fa {
            visibility: hidden;
            color: #c22362;
        }
   }
```

Comment: Your code is fine(though I agree with the answer below that you should be using `display:none;`), your phone probably has a width greater than 640px. Typically 768px is used for the mobile breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience, using `visibility: hidden;` is not a good idea if you are wanting to hide something via media queries.  Rather than specifying that, put this instead: `display: none;`

Visibility: hidden; just hides the content which will leave gaps on your website if viewed on a mobile device - using display: none; however, doesn't display that particular class or id period which is preferred and leaves no gaps.

Also, make sure you clear your cache - this too could be why you are not seeing any changes take effect.